# Should this tag be transformed in a [flicker] of light?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have the [flicker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/flicker) tag. Its usage guidance says:

> When something flickers it flashes repeatedly. Flickering in the Ask Ubuntu forums is generally referring to screen issues, or to describe an LED, such as,"The hard disk access light flickered."

Having a single tag for both screen flickering and other kinds of flickering is rather confusing.

Since the vast majority of the questions regarding this tag in Ask Ubuntu is about screen flickering, should the [flicker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/flicker) tag be renamed to [screen-flicker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/screen-flicker) or [screen-flickering](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/screen-flickering) (and its usage guidance edited accordingly)? Or as [muru has suggested in the comments](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19581/should-this-tag-be-transformed-in-a-flicker-of-light#comment42452_19581) should it be made a synonym of [visual-artifacts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/visual-artifacts)?

<sub>Thanks Zanna for [pointing up](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57730798#57730798) to the issue.</sub>

Comment: I don't see why should it have a tag at all. Who is an expert on screen flickering? Why would anyone follow a tag for screen flickering long term?

Comment: @muru While I agree that it isn't a tag that someone would follow, it could be useful when someone searches for questions about screen flickering issues by tag.

Comment: But why would you need a tag for searching either? It's not like "screen flickering" as a search term is going to be very noisy

Comment: Also for searching to be effective, someone has to be maintaining that tag and making sure it's applied right. If no one follows it, it will become unmaintained and useless in searching over a simple word search.

Comment: @muru It depends on the **user persona**, who is using the site. A **beginner**, unable to diagnose their problem might not even know that _drivers_ exist in a machine. They will see only until their screen, because that's in front of them. So they will come to the site and say, "My screen is flickering". Then, the **power-user** persona type, who knows about drivers and can help them (say, even specializes in drivers), can find these people by following the "(screen-)flicker" tag (along with the "drivers" tag too of course (to find the other well-informed people with these problems as well)).

Comment: In other words, knowing to use the "drivers" tag assumes a level of well-informedness. But not all site users are initially on that level.

Comment: @Levente yes, so read what I said again: unless someone follows the tag and makes sure it's correctly applied, it's useless. Are you going to do that?

Comment: @muru I appear to have answered your two "why" questions. As to whether I will do the maintenance: no, I won't.

Comment: @Levente then it's useless for **beginners** ***and*** **power users** alike.

Comment: And even if there were some users who wanted to help out on screen issues, I'd imagine they won't be just interested in screen flickering, but display issues in general and follow [tag:display], and I'd expect beginners to use that tag too.

Comment: @muru *"@Levente yes, so read what I said again: unless someone follows the tag and makes sure it's correctly applied, it's useless. Are you going to do that?"* That logic can be applied to all tags. However, not every tag has to be (has been) assigned to a single person to be responsible for it. The correct application of tags is both the OP's and the community's work.

Comment: @muru *"... I'd imagine they won't be just interested in screen flickering, but display issues in general and follow display, and I'd expect beginners to use that tag too."* If someone has experienced screen flickering issues and has managed to solve them, they could well be interested in following this tag. Also, the same could be said about the [`tearing`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tearing) tag. Should it also be removed and keep all screen issues under the `display` tag?

Comment: If such a person did manage to solve an issue, I'd bet they managed to learn something about their particular graphics card and associated driver (if any), and not about screen tearing or flickering in general. In fact, looking at [tag:tearing] and seeing how many of them aren't tagged with the appropriate graphics-card tags, I'd say [tag:tearing] (153 questions in 11 years) and [tag:flicker] (195 questions in 11 years, and up for renaming to boot) should either be synonymised to [tag:visual-artifacts] (129 questions in nearly 8 years), or all three should just be synonymised to [tag:display].

Comment: "The correct application of tags is both the OP's and the community's work" And it's patently obvious that unless you make that easy, neither the OP nor the community is going to do it. When a tag is too narrow, then the "community" in general is unlikely to be aware of it, so unlikely to add it to applicable questions that don't have it, and without followers, there won't be users who will bother removing it when misapplied to questions. IMO these tags are too narrow in scope.

Comment: There's also this 10-year-old clusterf**k: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1249/158442

Comment: @muru I like the idea of synonimizing all to `visual-artifacts`!

Comment: +1 for visual-artifacts I guess